# Firebase Storage not working due to dependency problem

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, dependencies, firebase-storage

I have an app where I'm using firebase authentication, firebase storage, firebase realtime database, firebase messaging and google map activity. But when I integrated firebase storage dependency, the app crashes. Tell me which versions should I use so that my app runs smoothly.

Here are the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'



    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.4.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.8.2'


    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.7'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

    implementation 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.6'

}
```

Please guide me which dependencies should be used.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [latest release notes of Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android):

> The latest Firebase BoM version contains the latest versions of each Firebase Android library.

Because you are using:

> I have an app where I'm using Firebase Authentication, Firebase Storage, Firebase Realtime Database, Firebase Messaging

Your Firebase dependency implementations should look like this:

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.5.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
```

As you can see there is no need to specify the version for each artifact.

Answer (score 0):

Use same dependencies of auth and storage

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:17.0.0'
```